# Overwrite and Append Csv output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a few custom objects which I am exporting all to the same csv so I use the -Append switch, however, I want it to overwrite the existing file with the same name, how can I do this?

```
(Get-Content filelocation) | set-content filelocation
Filelocation
```

At the end of my custom objects I use this code

```
$CSV | Export-Csv filelocation -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Currently doing this exports it all to the same CSV every time I run the script, making it so I have to delete the Csv before running the script again.

How can I sort this?

Comment: replace -append with -force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-Force` flag after you specify the FileLocation will make it overwrite.